# Spoiler component in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Is there a something like a spoiler component in Compose (that doesn't look too much Android-ish)? Or can it be done fast using `LazyVerticalGrid` or something else? I'm looking for a box that opens and clothes by clicking on its header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you look for is `AnimatedVisibility` Composable.

```
var visible by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

    Text("Spoiler", modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable {
            visible = !visible
        }
    )
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = visible) {
        Column {
            Text("Lorem ipsum...Rest of the text")
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedvisibility

Comment: Looks like a default component, but its animation is awkward.

Comment: Yeah, default animation looks awkward in some situations but in the link you can see other type of animations can be applied as well

Comment: I mean its lagging at some points, but maybe its because of debug version, phone or something else.

Comment: It's not lagging on my device but it's possible. You should check out actual performance in release mode with minifyEnabled true. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#config